# MassAssignmentException in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a Laravel newbie. I want to seed my database. When I run the seed command I get an exception

```
  [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException]
  username



db:seed [--class[="..."]] [--database[="..."]]
```

What am I doing wrong. The command I use is:

```
php artisan db:seed --class="UsersTableSeeder"
```

My seed class is as follows:

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()
    {
            User::truncate();
            User::create([
                'username' => 'PaulSheer',
                'email' => 'psheer@rute.co.za',
                'password' => '45678'
            ]);

            User::create([
                'username' => 'Stevo',
                'email' => 'steve@rute.co.za',
                'password' => '45678'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Read this section of Laravel doc : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Laravel provides by default a protection against mass assignment security issues. That's why you have to manually define which fields could be "mass assigned" :

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
}
```

---

**Warning :** be careful when you allow the mass assignment of critical fields like `password` or `role`. It could lead to a security issue because users could be able to update this fields values when you don't want to.

Comment: -1 While this works, the solution from Pascalculator is better in that it un-guards only when the mass-assignment is needed and not for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: You are right, in the specific context of database seeding, it should be better to unguard only during the seeding. But, because this answer seems to become a reference topic about `MassAssignmentException` and because it think my answer is a good generic solution, I will keep it as is.

Comment: Alexandre, I'm finding it hard to follow your logic. If you agree, you might as well change your own answer, even more so because it is becoming a reference topic. The answer you have suggested will indeed work, but isn't in compliance with the Laravel convention.

Comment: I keep my answer as is because I think it's a good general pattern (I use it in my projects) and because I think it isn't more or less in compliance with the Laravel convention than your answer (see the doc). But, because plurality of opinions is great and because your solution can be as good as mine, I upvoted it and I encourage others to read it :)

Comment: 'password' => bcrypt('45678')

Comment: To add to this... I'm using Laravel v5.2 and by default, all ``Model`` classes have ``protected $guarded`` set to ``[*]``. This means that all attributes (whether they're listed ``protected $fillable`` or not) are not mass assignable. To fix this, you need to specify ``protected $guarded = [];`` in the model (as mentioned in another answer).

Comment: Just getting into Laravel and followed this Laracast: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8. After adding the `protected $fillable` list I was still getting the MassException error. Not sure why but  after exiting artisan tinker and then entering it again, the error went away. Can't beat a good old off and on jobbie.

Comment: In my case, I had written **$filable**, with a single "l" and the correct one is **$fillable** with two

Comment: @AlexandreButynski I have the same problem but this is happening inside of the `RegisterController` where I need to create several other records depending on the `$user->id` and it's giving me the same error. Do you think that using the `$fillable` on the `[x] Model` may represent a security risk? where x = several other models that have a relationship with the `User Model`

Answer (score 32):

I am using Laravel 4.2.

the error you are seeing

```
[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException]
username
```

indeed is because the database is protected from filling en masse, which is what you are doing when you are executing a seeder. However, in my opinion, it's not necessary (and might be insecure) to declare which fields should be fillable in your model if you only need to execute a seeder.

In your seeding folder you have the DatabaseSeeder class:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */

    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        //$this->call('UserTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

This class acts as a facade, listing all the seeders that need to be executed. If you call the UsersTableSeeder seeder manually through artisan, like you did with the `php artisan db:seed --class="UsersTableSeeder"` command, you bypass this DatabaseSeeder class.

In this DatabaseSeeder class the command `Eloquent::unguard();` allows temporary mass assignment on all tables, which is exactly what you need when you are seeding a database. This unguard method is only executed when you run the `php aristan db:seed` command, hence it being temporary as opposed to making the fields fillable in your model (as stated in the accepted and other answers).

All you need to do is add the `$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');` to the run method in the DatabaseSeeder class and run `php aristan db:seed` in your CLI which by default will execute DatabaseSeeder.

**Also note** that you are using a plural classname Users, while Laraval uses the the singular form User. If you decide to change your class to the conventional singular form, you can simply uncomment the `//$this->call('UserTableSeeder');` which has already been assigned but commented out by default in the DatabaseSeeder class.

Comment: For the paranoid, and the purists: you will also find appreciation in using `\Eloquent::reguard();`, for after your Mass Assignments are complete.

Answer (score 11):

To make **all fields fillable**, just declare on your class:

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

This will enable you to call fill method without declare each field.

Comment: I don't want to use specific field in array. what should I do?

Answer (score 7):

Just add `Eloquent::unguard();` in the top of the run method when you do a seed, no need to create an `$fillable` array in all the models you have to seed.

Normally this is already specified in the `DatabaseSeeder` class. However because you're calling the `UsersTableSeeder` directly:

`php artisan db:seed --class="UsersTableSeeder"`

`Eloquent::unguard();` isn't being called and gives the error.

Answer (score 6):

I used this and have no problem:

```
protected $guarded=[];
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the  MassAssignmentException when I have extends my model like this.

```
class Upload extends Eloquent {

}
```

I was trying to insert array like this

```
Upload::create($array);//$array was data to insert.
```

**Issue has been resolve** when I created Upload Model as

```
class Upload extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();  // Important
}
```

Reference https://github.com/aidkit/aidkit/issues/2#issuecomment-21055670

Answer (score 1):

User proper model in your controller file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have table and fields on database you can simply use this command :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder --database=YOURDATABSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **fillable** to tell laravel which fields can be filled using an array.
By default, Laravel does not allow database fields to be updated via an array

```
Protected $fillable=array('Fields you want to fill using array');
```

The opposite of **fillable** is **guardable**.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a good way when you want to seeding database.**
Use [faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) instead of hard coding, and before all this maybe it's better to truncate tables.

Consider this example :

```
    // Truncate table.  
    DB::table('users')->truncate();

    // Create an instance of faker.
    $faker = Faker::create();

    // define an array for fake data.
    $users = [];

    // Make an array of 500 users with faker.
    foreach (range(1, 500) as $index)
    {
        $users[] = [
            'group_id' => rand(1, 3),
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'company' => $faker->company,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            'address' => "{$faker->streetName} {$faker->postCode} {$faker->city}",
            'about' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 20, $variableNbWords = true),
            'created_at' => new DateTime,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime,
        ];
    }

    // Insert into database.
    DB::table('users')->insert($users);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use the OOP method of inserting, you don't need to worry about mass-action/fillable properties:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'Stevo';
$user->email = 'steve@rute.co.za';
$user->password = '45678';
$user->save();
```