# Laravel 4 Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hei, I already searched many answers out there but could not solve this problem.

Here is the code for my migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateActiveTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('activations', function($table)
        {
            $table->bigInteger('id')->primary();
            $table->tinyInteger('token');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('activations');
    }
}
```

For model (*models/Activation.php*)

```
<?php

class Activation extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'activations';
    protected $guarded = array();
}
```

And i am calling Activation table like this.

```
Activation::create(['id' => 2, 'token' => 1231]);
```

Seriously i have no idea what's wrong here. And i am newbie at laravel 4. Hope somebody with teach me whats happening and how to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MassAssignmentException in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280136/massassignmentexception-in-laravel)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the `$fillable` property in your `Activation` class when you use [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment).

```
class Activation extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'activations';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'token'];
}
```

Comment: Try removing $guarded line. Do you really want to manually assign id?

Comment: is there any reason to make a auto incremented id? while all i need is to enter a id of my own, I tried

Comment: This is common in linking tables. Other than that it avoids to enforce data integrity in the application side. In your case Activation should have an auto-incremented id and something like member_id which you can relate to a Client model with Eloquent.

Comment: I meant Member model.