# 4.2 Laravel does not create a database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I try to insert data into the database, I get the following error:

[2014-09-27 09:02:40] production.ERROR: in E:Webxampphtdocslaravelbootstrapcompiled.php:6397, exception 'IlluminateDatabaseEloquentMassAssignmentException' with message 'name'.

in the file `new.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

    <h1>New Author page</h1>    

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'authors/create', 'method' => 'POST')) }}


    <p>
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('bio', 'Biography:') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('bio') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::submit('Add Author') }}
    </p>

    {{ Form::close() }}

@endsection
```

and my route is defined in `routes.php` as:

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'AuthorsController@index', 'as'=>'authors'));
Route::post('authors/create', array('uses'=>'AuthorsController@create', 'as'=>'create_author'));
```

and the following code in my Authorscontroller.php file:

```
    public function create()
    {
        Author::create(array(
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'bio' => Input::get('bio')
            ));
        return Redirect::route('authors');
    }
```

What is the issue? Laravel 4.2 is the version I'm using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747061/laravel-4-illuminate-database-eloquent-massassignmentexception-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your model you have to give private $guarded = array('id'); here id is primary key of the table this means when you use create or update method which uses bulk assignment the given fields in guarded array will not be updated! you must define this propery in your model to use mass assignment using create() or update() method

```
private $guarded = array('id'); //id is primary key where it can be any field which will not be updated in mass assignment
```