# Laravel create method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to store an array using Laravel's `create` method

```
$input = Input::all();
$new_media = $this->media->create($input);
```

or

```
$input = Input::all();
$new_media = Media::create($input);
```

both codes does not work.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Method [create] does not exist.
```

Laravel documentation here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

From laravel docs

```
// Create a new user in the database...
$user = User::create(array('name' => 'John'));
```

Media Model

```
<?php

class Media extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'media';

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules_video = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required'
    );
    public static $rules_image = array(
        'title' => 'required'
    );

    public function category(){
        return Category::find($this->category_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the Media model extends Eloquent ?

Comment: I guesss there is no such method, instead you can use something like this $user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();

where User is your model class which is extending Eloquent

Comment: @Richie Yes it does!

Comment: @HaykAghabekyan Right, but this method used to work fine. Just don't know what's wrong now.

Comment: edit your question to include your Media model

Comment: @Richie done! added media model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to setup [Mass Assignments](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) when using `create`, `fill` or `update`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747106/397195).

Remove your `guarded` property and create a new one called `fillable` as an array with the allowed fields to be updated with mass assignments.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'url'];
```