# Laravel ::create method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem when I try to create new User with `User::create[]` method.

I read [Laravel create method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293177/laravel-create-method) this problem, but it does not help me:

Below is my User model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','phone','rating'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Here, my controller code:

```
public function create() {
    $input = Request::all();
    User::create[$input];
    return $input;
}
```

PhpShtorm shows me this notification:

> Constant create not found in ...

How can I fix it, and create new user?

Comment: `User::create($input);`create is not an array it is a method.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/b7cGcKo.png

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ please add what you mention in answer, because it right answer .

Comment: @ДимаСвободин Your problem is your IDE is searching for magic methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access `create` as an array, it is a method, like so: `create()`. Change the square brackets in the code below.

Your *IDE* may not recognize the method because it is called using `magic methods`. If you want to properly recognize the method, use [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

```
public function create() {
    $input = Request::all();
 // $input = request()->all() <-- Using a helper function 
    User::create($input); // <-- Change this
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: @ДимаСвободин The IDE cannot find it because it is called using `magic methods` but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `create()`. Assuming you want to return the created user, then do this.

```
public function create() 
{
    $user = User::create(request()->all());
    return $user;
}
```

If you really wanted to return the input then you can do this.

```
public function create()
{
    $inputs = request()->all();
    User::create($inputs);
    return $inputs;
}
```

Also ignore the warnings on magic methods and fluent syntaxes in IDE. Laravel is not the kindest when it comes to that. You can use this package to help with that.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Answer (score 1):

This syntax look for a constant with name `bar` in class `Foo`.

```
Foo::bar
```

If bar is a method, ... you need to call it with parenthesys

```
Foo::bar()
```

If you write Foo::bar['foo']; you expect to find a constant like

```
class Foo
{
    const bar = ['foo' => 'bar'];
}
```

I dont think this is the right syntax

You are in App namespace. Exists App\User class? And App\User class have a method 'create'?

Sometimes IDE show errors even if code works perfectly.

Comment: Is an IDE issue: check if code works on your browser. Sometimes IDE do not recognize code.