# Simple insert using eloquent in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to insert single data into db in Laravel 4 but failed to do so after trying for 3 hrs.

Below is code snippet,

**Model**

**User.php**

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table='users';
  protected $protected = array();
}
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateUserInfoTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('cntNo');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}

}
```

**Controller**

**UserController.php**

```
public function post_create()
{
    User::create(array('name'=>Input::get('name'),'cntNo'=>Input::get('cntno')));
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('new/create', array('uses'=>'UserController@post_create'));
```

But I am not able to even insert into database.

**app-->config-->database.php**

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => 'mysql',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => array(

    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laravel_user',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'sa',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'pgsql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'forge',
        'username' => 'forge',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ),

    'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),

);
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Latest One after setting debug => true in **app.php**

[image]

Comment: Have you selected the correct database? Does your database have the table? Are you sure `Input::get('name')` and `Input::get('cntno')` are set? Just some suggestions :)

Comment: `Input::get('name')` and `Input::get('cntno')` both are having valid values(i.e. they are set), How to know that you have selected the correct database or table? I have changed the `database.php` pls check the edit.

Comment: Have you runned your migrations?

Comment: What error do you get? I can see a few things that might cause it

Comment: @Jerodev : Yes ,I have also mentioned the **Migration** Code above , pls check it.(The table is created properly through Migration)

Comment: @DavidJones : How to check the error in `Sublime Text 3` editor , whereas on the page it is giving me `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`. Pls consider it as I am very new to this technology.

Comment: The things that I can Create through **Migration** successfully is(are) Database ('laravel_user') and Table('users').

Comment: Is there any more info on the page where it says `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`. If yes, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: There should be a big message on the page, usually on the right hand side at the top. You can't miss it.

Comment: @Jerodev: Thnx for ur reply.There's nothing else displayed on the page other than this still I have attached the Screenshot , Check the edit.

Comment: You need to turn debug to true in your app/config/app.php file to get more information

Comment: @DavidJones: Thnx for that info ,Pls check the latest edit with new Screenshot attached. Btw it is giving `MassAssignmentException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Laravel docs for Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment). All you need to do add a `fillable` property to your model:

```
protected $fillable = array('name', 'cntNo');
```

That will allow you to 'mass assign' your properties in a `create` method.

---

Alternatively, you could insatiate a new User object and individually set it's values:

```
public function post_create()
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->cntNo = Input::get('cntno');

    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Thnx!! that worked..! Btw I have used `protected $protected = array();` which is counterpart of `$fillable` still why it didn't worked?

Comment: Actually, the property you are thinking about is `guarded`. `guarded` is also covered in the [mass assignment docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 1):

Refer: 
[MassAssignmentException in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280136/massassignmentexception-in-laravel)

Laravel provide by default a protection against mass assignment security issues. That's why you have to manually define which fields could be "mass assigned"

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table='users';
  protected $guarded = array('id');
  protected $fillable = array('name', 'cntNo');
}
```

Comment: Hi abhijith, I think it is `$guarded` instead of `$protected`