# Laravel 5 : MassAssignmentException in Model.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mass-assignment

I am getting this error:

> MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 448: _token

When I am using `create` method. Please review code below:

**Contacts.php** (Model):

```
class Contacts extends Model
{
    protected $table = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

**ContactsController.php** (Controller):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{        
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $contacts = Contacts::Create($inputs);
    return redirect()->route('contacts.index');
}
```

Comment: [MassAssignmentException in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22280136/6521116)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

For the [Mass Assignment Exception](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment): you should specify all the fields of the model that you want to be mass-assignable through create or update operations on the property `$fillable`:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Besides, the field `$table` should contain only the model's table name:

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name';
```

Comment: How could I forget this. Thank you. Works.

Answer (score 6):

This might happen in case if you have used the wrongly imported the class. if you are using the User Model.

Wrong Import

```
// mostly IDE suggestion
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
```

Correct Model Import

```
use App\User;
```

i have gone through this. might help someone.

Comment: Yes it did (: Auto import in IDE may confuse sometimes

Answer (score 5):

You can all column fillable:

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

Add your model.

Answer (score 1):

You need only to add the following to your Model (`Contact`):

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

For example:

```
class Contacts extends Model { 
   protected $table = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at']; 
   protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at' ]; 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a but more detail. Are you suggesting that they don't need the `store` function, that your provided `$fillable` should replace `$table`, or something else?

Comment: Mr Sandeep want to insert data in the contact table so he need to go in the Contact Model and Put 
```protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];```

Comment: So you suggest that this should be added to the his `Contact` class, in addition to the code he already provided?

Comment: Yes Exactly ! like This

```class Contacts extends Model
{
    protected $table = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'mobile', 'email', 'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at' ];
}```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above fails, you can try  following. 
Put following after namespace.

```
use Eloquent;
```

Put following at the start of your `store` method.

```
Eloquent::unguard();
```

like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{        
   Eloquent::unguard();
   $inputs = $request->all();
   $contacts = Contacts::Create($inputs);
   return redirect()->route('contacts.index');
}
```

This is not recommended though, as this makes things vulnerable to attacks. But if you need a quick fix this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check Model you have Imported or Not. If not then use this.

```
<?php 

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth; 
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
 use App\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting the $fillable or $guarded in the app\Contacts.php file and not the app\Http\Controllers\ContactsController.php file. It should be obvious, but it can be overlooked.