# Laravel 5.5 MassAssignmentException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm following the Laravel From Scratch tutorial series, I'm currently at the part that you are creating a comment system for your articles system. But I'm having a problem, I don't really know what the error is saying at this point.

**The error:**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException
body
```

**The comment model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

**The post model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function addComment($body)
    {
        $this->comments()->create(compact('body'));
    }
}
```

**The route I made:**

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

**The comments controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Post $post)
    {
        $post->addComment(request('body'));

        return back();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565515/laravel-5-massassignmentexception-in-model-php/34565540#34565540)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 : MassAssignmentException in Model.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565515/laravel-5-massassignmentexception-in-model-php)

Comment: Add `protected $fillable = [ 'db_column1','db_column'  ]` in your two models.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Explanation of this error

This is a security feature of Laravel. It is designed to protect you against form manipulation when using mass assignments.

For example on a sign-up form: When you have an `is_admin` column in your database, a user simply could manipulate your form to set `is_admin` to `true` on your server, and therefore in your database. This security feature prevents that by using a whitelist to define safe fields.

---

## How to fix that

You need to set a `$fillable` property on your model. It's value must be an array containing all fields that are safe to mass assignable (like username, email address, ...).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    # This property!
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    // ...
}
```

See "Mass assignment" in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: This did the trick, thank you for giving me a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Mass assignment is when you send an array to the model creation, basically setting a bunch of fields on the model in a single go, rather than one by one, something like what you did here:

```
public function addComment($body)
{
    $this->comments()->create(compact('body'));
}
```

You need to add the field you are populating to the fillable array in `Comments.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

As the documentation states:

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single
>   line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the
>   method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a
>   fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models
>   protect against mass-assignment by default.

Hope this helps you.